# How can I write this Query in another way

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table class_group, the column list_students_id contains text with comma separated user IDs of the users in the current group group. 
Example : group id :1 -- group name : group 1 -- list_students_id : 2,43,45,50...
I know this is not optimal but I can't change the database structure.
I want to query the group name if the student is in the group and I wrote the following code and I feel it's not optimal

```
SELECT user.firstname,user.lastname,user.username,user.alt_id,user.email,class_group.group_name
FROM user LEFT JOIN class_group 
ON (class_group.list_students_id LIKE CONCAT(user.id,',%') OR class_group.list_students_id LIKE CONCAT('%,',user.id,',%'))
```

Any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really bad decisions on database design.  You should know the correct way to implement this type of structure.  SQL has a great data structure for lists.  It is called a *table* not a *string*.

In any case, I think you want:

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.username, u.alt_id, u.email, cg.group_name
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     class_group cg
     ON find_in_set(u.id, list_students_id) > 0;
```

Note that this query cannot make use of an index, so performance will generally be worse than using the appropriate data structure.

Comment: Thanks man, this saved me about 60 ms. And yeah I agree I'm stuck with this db schema at the company because they say that it was optimized for a certain function and they didn't know we're gonna use it elsewhere and changing the db now would need refactoring a lot of code so it's kinda sad.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make use of [INSTR()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php) function

```
SELECT user.firstname,user.lastname,user.username,user.alt_id,user.email,
class_group.group_name 
FROM user LEFT JOIN class_group 
ON INSTR(class_group.list_students_id, user.id) > 0;
```

Comment: this doesn't work if there is a number in the list that has the user id inside it (eg : user.id =71 -- element : 571 or 271 ....) but thanks for the help anyway